# How to compile a GUI in Java using Eclipse with the given code

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

So this was the example given in the notes for my current project. Usually I run the the example code and play around with it to see how everything works. However this particular code does not compile. Can someone please tell me why?

I created a Java project followed by a Class named Gui (as you can see) using eclipse which is the program we have been using all semester.

```
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Gui 
{
public class GuiApp extends JFrame
{
    private DrawingPanel panel;
    public GuiApp()
    {
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);//x,y,w,h of window
        panel = new DrawingPanel();
        this.setContentPane(panel);
    }
    public void main(String [] args)
    {
        GuiApp f = new GuiApp();
        f.setTitle("Smiley");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel 
{
    public DrawingPanel()
    {
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        drawFlower(g, 20, 10, 10);
    }
}
public void drawFlower(Graphics g,int x,int y,int s)
{
    g.setColor(Color.PINK); 
    g.fillOval(x, y, s, s);
    g.fillOval(x-s, y-s, s, s);
    g.fillOval(x, y-s, s, s);  
    g.fillOval(x-s, y, s, s);     
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW); 
    g.fillOval(x-s/2, y-s/2, s, s);     
}
```

}

Comment: I'll be easier to help if you also provide the error message

Comment: No error message but when I try to compile the option to Run as -> "Java Application" isnt there.

Comment: Try making the main method "static".

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type

 at Gui$GuiApp.main(Gui.java:23)
 is the error i get when doing so

Comment: Why are you calling the main method in an inner Class?

Comment: Thats the way i was shown to do it, plus when trying to separate it from the inner class I get even more errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple classes nested, and therefore you cant declare main method in nested one. Just remove class Gui, or make a separate file for every class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GuiApp extends JFrame
{

private DrawingPanel panel;
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel 
{
    public DrawingPanel()
    {
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        drawFlower(g, 20, 10, 10);
    }
}
public void drawFlower(Graphics g,int x,int y,int s)
{
    g.setColor(Color.PINK); 
    g.fillOval(x, y, s, s);
    g.fillOval(x-s, y-s, s, s);
    g.fillOval(x, y-s, s, s);  
    g.fillOval(x-s, y, s, s);     
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW); 
    g.fillOval(x-s/2, y-s/2, s, s);     
}
public GuiApp()
{
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);//x,y,w,h of window
    panel = new DrawingPanel();
    this.setContentPane(panel);
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    GuiApp f = new GuiApp();
    f.setTitle("Smiley");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your Program is that you are calling the `main` method in an inner class which is totally wrong. Your `main` method is the execution start of your program which cannot reside in an inner class, because the `main` method needs to be called before any other code in your program.

You can resolve your error by removing your `GUI` class from your code and putting the `drawFlower()` method inside the `DrawingPanel` class. Then it will work fine.

### Solution:

```
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.*;

public class GuiApp extends JFrame
{
    private DrawingPanel panel;
    public GuiApp()
    {
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);//x,y,w,h of window
        panel = new DrawingPanel();
        this.setContentPane(panel);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GuiApp f = new GuiApp();
        f.setTitle("Smiley");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class DrawingPanel extends JPanel 
{
    public DrawingPanel()
    {
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        drawFlower(g, 20, 10, 10);
    }

public void drawFlower(Graphics g,int x,int y,int s)
{
    g.setColor(Color.PINK); 
    g.fillOval(x, y, s, s);
    g.fillOval(x-s, y-s, s, s);
    g.fillOval(x, y-s, s, s);  
    g.fillOval(x-s, y, s, s);     
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW); 
    g.fillOval(x-s/2, y-s/2, s, s);     
}
}
```

There **That** will work!!!